# jQuery from iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I am using the jquery.autoellipsis-1.0.10.js to make an 2 line ellipsis.  The pages are made in classic ASP.  Initial page load the ellipsis works great.  We have pagination that is done via a very old method, the page is run in an iframe and then rewrites the innerHTML of a div tag.  However, when loading through the iframe the ellipsis doesn't work.

HERE IS CODE FROM IFRAME:

```
<%
pstrOut = "<div class=""block"">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit</div>"
%>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.autoellipsis-1.0.10.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.block").ellipsis();
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
div.block {
  width:<%=nVideoWidth%>px;  
  max-height:30px;
  min-height:15px;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var jstr = '';
<%=cUtil.ToJS(pstrOut,"jstr") %>
top.parent.document.getElementById('TargetDIV').innerHTML = jstr;
</script>
</head>
```

cUtil.ToJS:

```
<%     
Function toJS(val,valVar)
Dim pstrOut
If isNull(val) Then
  Exit Function
End If
If valVar = "" Then
  valVar = "jstr"
End If

Select Case valVar
  Case "-1"
    pstrOut = Replace(val, "'", "\'")
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut, ";", "\;")
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut, ",", "\,")
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut,vbLF,vbCr)
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut, vbCr, "\n';")
toJS = pstrOut
  Case "0"
pstrOut = Replace(val, "'", "")
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut, ";", "")
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut, ",", " ")
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut,vbLF,vbCr)
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut, vbCr, "")
toJS = pstrOut
  Case Else
pstrOut = Replace(val, "'", "\'")
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut, ";", "\;")
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut, ",", "\,")
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut,vbLF,vbCr)
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut,vbCrLf,vbCr)
pstrOut = Replace(pstrOut, vbCr, "\n';" & vbCr & valVar & " += '")
toJS = valVar & " += '" & pstrOut & "\n';" & vbCr
  End Select

End Function
```

I need the ellipsis to work on the parent page once the iframe has run and output to the parent page.  Any ideas, as I have next to no knowledge about jQuery.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: only the ellipsis don't work or are you not getting any html in the div ?

Comment: just the ellipsis is not working..!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var jstr = '';
<%=cUtil.ToJS(pstrOut,"jstr") %>
$("#TargetDIV",parent.document).html(jstr).ellipsis();
</script>
```